# 5 Letter Word, Removing letters

Tags: riddle, word, word-problem

Take away my first letter, and I still sound the same. 

Take away my last letter, I still sound the same. 
Even take away my letter in the middle, I will still sound the same. 
I am a five letter word. 
What am I?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an old one.

The answer is:

> EMPTY

Because:

> MPTY still sounds like EMPTY,
>  EMPT still sounds like EMPTY,
> and EMTY still (sort of) sounds like EMPTY.

And, of course, you can

> take all 3 away and M T is left.

Answer (score 7):

A postman, because he/she will be a postman without any letters.

Comment: A vote of approval because of how well it fits the clues, even if it doesn't quite fit into 5 letters

Answer (score 6):

You are:

> aisle
>  Remove the first : isle
>  Remove the last : aisl
>  Remove the middle : aile
>  (Obviously assuming s remains silent even after removing the first/last)