# 5 Letter Word, Removing letters - Part 2

Tags: riddle, word, letters

Following [Part 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14872/5-letter-word-removing-letters):

Take away my second letter, and I still sound the same. 

Take away my third letter, I still sound the same. 
Even take away my fourth and fifth letters, I will still sound the same. 
I am a five letter word. 
What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> Queue

Because:

> **Qeue** I would try to pronounce the same,
>  **Que** would sound like queue, unless you speak Spanish

And Finally

> The letter Q sounds like the full five letter word.

Approaching each line as a separate removal, we have:

> Qeue
>  Quee (Kwee, close to Queue)
>  Que (Again, unless you are Spanish)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is:

> a crowd heckling: "BOOOO".

Take away the third letter:

> BOOO

Take away the second letter:

> BOOO

Take away the fourth and fifth letters:

> BOO