# Five letter words at cross purposes

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, crosswords

Please solve the four clues, each is five letters, which would complete the crossword.

Across

1. Take away my first letter I sound the same, then take away my last letter I sound the same,  even take away another letter I  sound the same.
2. About eg tan00

Down

1. I am the largest number which - spelled out - is five letters long.
2. 13  14  15  16  17  18  19 ?

[image]

Comment: A cryptic crossword is a specific type of puzzle. Please check tag wikis before using them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All:

> [image]

1. Across: Take away my first letter I sound the same, then take away my last letter I sound the same, even take away another letter I sound the same.

   > EMCEE - a [master of ceremonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_ceremonies) (M CEE; M CE; MC)
2. Across: About eg tan00

   > AGENT - [Ian Fleming's 00 agents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/00_Agent) (anagram of eg tan;)

1. Down: I am the largest number which - spelled out - is five letters long.

   > OMEGA - smallest infinite [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Ordinals_extend_the_natural_numbers) number
2. Down: 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ?

   > TEENS - what these numbers are

Comment: Beautiful! Good work :)

Answer (score 8):

Aha! There's a trick.

> One box is already filled:

giving these answers:

> EMPTY, AGENT (credit @Arth), OMEGA, 2TENS
>
>  [image: filled grid]

Comment: 'Each is five letters' - interesting suggestion though!

Comment: @Arth Fair point. :(

Comment: @Will It is a tricky question but (One box is already filled - caused by my bad Paint) - only someone really ingenious could have thought of that!.  Only one of the 4 answers hasn't been found somewhere on this page yet. Two above of good graphic are correct. I think your answer is even better than mine by the way.

Answer (score 4):

Some other possibles..

1 Across:

> EIDER - Bit of a stretch, IDER, EIDE, EIDR.. or EMPTY (@GintasK) - fits with OMEGA

2 Across:

> AGENT - Anagram of eg tan, also known as a 00 from James Bond - fits with OMEGA

1 Down:

> LIMIT, could be OMEGA (@Will)

2 Down:

> TEENS

Comment: Well, I got two of them :)

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

Across:

Take away my first letter I sound the same, then take away my last letter I sound the same, even take away another letter I sound the same.

> Likely to be EMPTY (@Gintas K)

About eg tan00

> 

Down:

I am the largest number which - spelled out - is five letters long.

> OMEGA (Thanks to @Will): This is the last Greek letter, has five letters, and a Greek numeric value of 800.

13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ?

> 20, but twenty is six letters, so maybe VINGT (the french spelling)? SCORE (@Gintas K)

Comment: There are larger 5-letter numbers (i think 3)...

Comment: I also think 3. (Not any more, because Moose has updated the answer.)

Comment: I've deleted my answer, add Empty to yours :)

Comment: 20 could be SCORE or ICOSA/ICOSI, but doesn't fit anywhere either :/ http://gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/numbers/words/intro.htm

Comment: SIXTY is definitely right: http://chesswanks.com/num/a052196.html So EMPTY might not be the right one

Comment: I'm also sure about EMPTY, this was posted on Puzzling.SE before: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14872/5-letter-word-removing-letters But EMPTY and SIXTY don't fit, is there a mistake @Tom ?

Comment: @Gintas K - I don't think there's a mistake. :)

Comment: [`OMEGA`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Ordinals_extend_the_natural_numbers) would fit with `EMPTY`